# Type of usage in this example/accuracy

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english

After entering the fountain of youth, she was now young **not old.**

After entering the fountain of youth, she was now young **and not old.**

Are both these ok. Any difference?

Can you leave out the comma before not old at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, you need a comma. "... young, not old."

With that change both sentences are grammatically correct, but I think the emphasis is off. I would write, "After entering the fountain of youth, she was no longer old. Now she was young."